# How Can I Style Page Numbers When Converting Markdown to PDF with pandoc?

Tags: css, pdf, pandoc

I am using `pandoc` to convert a markdown file to a PDF with page numbers in the headings, with a command like:

```sh
pandoc \
--pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf \
--pdf-engine-opt="--header-right" \
--pdf-engine-opt="[page]" \
-c _style.css \
"$markdown" -o "$pdf"
```

I am able to style the body of the pages with the `_style.css` file, but I cannot figure out how to set styles for the page numbers in the headings.

Specifically, I want to set the `font-family`, `font-size`, and `margin` for the heading displaying the number for each page.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out via https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

I needed to use more `--pdf-engine-opt` flags:

```sh
pandoc \
--pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf \
--pdf-engine-opt="--header-right" --pdf-engine-opt="[page] of [topage]" \
--pdf-engine-opt="--header-font-name" --pdf-engine-opt="Courier" \
--pdf-engine-opt="--header-font-size" --pdf-engine-opt="10" \
-c _style.css \
"$markdown" -o "$pdf";
```